# How to keep scroll at bottom by default when using select option tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select option tag with scrollbar and some contents in it. Now I want to keep the scrollbar at the bottom when we click on the dropdown list to see the content.

```
Var myObj = document.getElementById("scroll");
myObj.scrollTop = myObj.scrollHeight;
```

I used this script code but it dint work for select option tag

Comment: Can you post your HTML code?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: When do you run that code? When the dropdown is visible?

Comment: Can you tell me logic for scroll should be bottom by default in the dropdown using jquery and select html tag

Comment: _"but it dint work for select option tag"_ - I would not have expected it to to begin with. A select field is different than "normal" HTML elements, much of the rendering is handed over to the underlying OS. I don't think there is any way to achieve what you want, not with a native select element - you will likely have to go for a custom replacement, if you really need this kind of functionality.

Comment: What kind of custom replacement?