# Is it possible to keep scrollbar positioned at bottom by default?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I have select option tag with scrollbar to view the contents in the dropdown. I want that scroll should be positioned in the bottom when we click select item.

```
jquery code

$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#textin1').click(function() {
        var pos = $('#textin1').offset();
        pos.top += $('#textin1').width();
        
        $('#dropdown').fadeIn(100);
       $('#dropdown').scrollTop($('#dropdown').find('li:contains("'+$('#textin1').val()+'")').position().top);
        return false;
    });

    $('#dropdown li').click(function() {
        $('#textin1').val($(this).text());
        $('#dropdown li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(100);
    });
});
```

Comment: The code you have shown tries to select `li` elements, so what you have is not an _actual_ `select` element then, I am guessing? Please present a proper [mre] of your issue.

Comment: <span id="plantimefromdd" style="position:relative;" >
    <input id="textin1" name="textin1" type="text" style="width:80px;text-align:center;" value="" />
    <select id="dropdown1">
    <option>00:00</option>
    <option>01:00</option>
    <option>02:00</option>
    </select>
<ul id="dropdown">
    <li>00:00</li>
    <li>01:00</li>
    <li>02:00</li>
</ul>
</span>

Comment: This questions is worded very similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76470461/9038475), but has more code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe it work for you

```js
const scrolling = document.getElementById("scroll");

const config = { childList: true };

const callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
  for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === "childList") {
      window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    }
  }
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(scrolling, config);
```